# Replace string with empty string except certain word using R

Tags: r, gsub

Good day, I want to gsub all string with " " except INDIVIDUAL/BUSINESS then mutate in a new column called business_type. I've tried many methods but fail. Thanks in advance.

```
text <- c("|Name:James Indiana|type:INDIVIDUAL|Id::G123456789&M|Location:Indonesia|", "|Name:James Bond|type:BUSINESS|Id::G&987654321M|Location:Indonesia|")
```

The output will be like this

```
business_type    
INDIVIDUAL    
BUSINESS
```

I am using

```r
mutate(business_type = gsub("[^(\\bINDIVIDUAL\\b)(\\bBUSINESS\\b)]+"," ",x)
```

This method removes other strings but exclude some uppercase letter from other strings.

```r
mutate(business_type = gsub("^/(?!INDIVIDUAL$)(?!BUSINESS$)[a-z0-9A-Z:&|]+=$"," ",x)
```

does not either. I also try `^/(?!ignoreme)([a-z0-9]+)$` regex but it's not working.

Comment: *I've tried many methods but fail.* - What failed for you? Please show the last attempt and explain what is wrong to see what issue you have got.

Comment: `mutate(business_type = gsub("[^(\\bINDIVIDUAL\\b)(\\bBUSINESS\\b)]+"," ",x)`. This method remove other string but exclude some uppercase letter from other string.
`mutate(business_type = gsub("^/(?!INDIVIDUAL$)(?!BUSINESS$)[a-z0-9A-Z:&|]+=$"," ",x)`. I also try `^/(?!ignoreme)([a-z0-9]+)$` method but not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```r
mutate(business_type = gsub("\\b(?:INDIVIDUAL|BUSINESS)\\b(*SKIP)(*F)|(?s)."," ",x, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/JKIhLb/1/).

**Regex details**:

- `\b(?:INDIVIDUAL|BUSINESS)\b` - match either an `INDIVIDUAL` or `BUSINESS` as whole words and
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - skip the match and go on matching from the failure location
- `|` - or
- `(?s).` - match any char including line break chars (`(?s)` is a singleline flag that makes `.` match any chars in a PCRE regex).

Comment: Thanks for the help. You're the best Wiktor. I noticed that regex in R a bit different than global.

Comment: @Afiq Not sure what you mean by "global", there is no "default" regex flavor. Some think it is PCRE, some think it is POSIX, but it's not true. Regex libraries are all different and you can't expect `\w` will match the same thing even in base R `gsub` with `perl=TRUE` (so, PCRE regex library) and *stringr* `str_replace_all` (powered by the ICU regex library). Here, I am using the PCRE regex library, and it has very convenient `(*SKIP)(*F)` verbs that help match and skip certain patterns, while matching others.

Comment: I understand. You really gave me a great insight about Regex.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str_extract` to extract the words that you are interested in.

```
stringr::str_extract(text, 'INDIVIDUAL|BUSINESS')
#[1] "INDIVIDUAL" "BUSINESS"
```

In base R,

```
regmatches(text, regexpr('INDIVIDUAL|BUSINESS', text))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Ronak. This method can extract the desired output but it'll be bit problem when I try to mutate later.

Comment: I don't know how exactly that would be a problem. `mutate(business_type 
 = stringr::str_extract(text, 'INDIVIDUAL|BUSINESS')` should work similarly.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. At first, I mistakenly put string and pattern at wrong place for str_extract, confused with gsub method. I didnt realize that str_extract can get me the desired output too.